# regular expression to remove comment javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using below regular expression to remove comments from string

```
<\!{1}\-{2}(.*?)\-{2}\s*>
```

This is working fine except for mult-iline string

```
var search = '<\!{1}\-{2}(.*?)\-{2}\s*>';

  var re = new RegExp(search, "gm");

  var subject = <multi-line string>;
  result = subject.replace(re, '');
```

what should I do to get it working with multiline strings

Comment: `<   !--   --    >` ←  This is not a comment.

Comment: A bad idea. Consider: `var s = "<!--"; a = b + c; s = "-->";`

Answer (score 2):

`.` does not allow linebreaks.

This one should work:

```
^(<\!\-{2})((.|\s)*?)\-{2}>$
```

Fix:

```
<!--[\S\s]*?-->
```

I removed the \s at the beginning and the end of the expression and added it in the middle so multiline-comments are allowed.

But you shoud have a look at BartKs comment ;)

regards

Comment: IMO, `--` is more to the point than `-{2}`, and `(.|\s)` could be replaced by `[\s\S]`. Also, `!` and `-` don't need escaping.

Comment: For the meat of the expression, wouldn't we just want ([^\-]*), question mark. (I would have felt bad ending this comment with a '?' when it could easily be construed as part of the regex, which is not the case.)  Edit: It would fail on <!-- - -->, I haven't had my morning coffee.

Comment: I made a slight edit: the class `[\S|\s]` does not need to contain the `|` (OR): inside a character class, `|` just matches the literal `"|"`. Also, The regex doesn't need to be anchored with `^` and `$` and `[\s\S]` does not need to be grouped by parenthesis. But @Sourabh should be aware that replacing comments like that could  result in unexpected behavior as I commented under his question.